# How can I configure no of classification classes/labels for StreamingLogisticRegressionWithSGD

Tags: apache-spark-mllib

I am new to Spark MLlib. I am trying to implement StreamingLogisticRegressionWithSGD model. Very little information is provided for it in Spark docs. When I enter `2,22-22-22` on socket stream  I am getting

```
ERROR DataValidators: Classification labels should be 0 or 1. Found 1 invalid labels
```

I understand that it is expecting me to enter features with label 0 or 1 but I really want to know if I can configure it for more labels.
I do not know how to set number of classes for classification for StreamingLogisticRegressionWithSGD.

Thanks!

**Code**

```
package test;

import java.util.List;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.StreamingLogisticRegressionWithSGD;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Durations;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaReceiverInputDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;

public class SLRPOC {

    private static StreamingLogisticRegressionWithSGD slrModel;

    private static int numFeatures = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[3]").setAppName("SLRPOC");
        SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf);
        StreamingContext ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Durations.seconds(10));
        JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(ssc);

        slrModel = new StreamingLogisticRegressionWithSGD().setStepSize(0.5).setNumIterations(10).setInitialWeights(Vectors.zeros(numFeatures));

        slrModel.trainOn(getDStreamTraining(jssc));
        slrModel.predictOn(getDStreamPrediction(jssc)).foreachRDD(new Function<JavaRDD<Double>, Void>() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 5287086933555760190L;

            @Override
            public Void call(JavaRDD<Double> v1) throws Exception {
                List<Double> list = v1.collect();
                for (Double d : list) {
                    System.out.println(d);
                }
                return null;
            }
        });

        jssc.start();
        jssc.awaitTermination();
    }

    public static JavaDStream<LabeledPoint> getDStreamTraining(JavaStreamingContext context) {
        JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> lines = context.socketTextStream("localhost", 9998);

        return lines.map(new Function<String, LabeledPoint>() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1268686043314386060L;

            @Override
            public LabeledPoint call(String data) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("Inside LabeledPoint call : ----- ");
                String arr[] = data.split(",");
                double vc[] = new double[3];
                String vcS[] = arr[1].split("-");
                int i = 0;
                for (String vcSi : vcS) {
                    vc[i++] = Double.parseDouble(vcSi);
                }
                return new LabeledPoint(Double.parseDouble(arr[0]), Vectors.dense(vc));
            }
        });
    }

    public static JavaDStream<Vector> getDStreamPrediction(JavaStreamingContext context) {
        JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> lines = context.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999);

        return lines.map(new Function<String, Vector>() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1268686043314386060L;

            @Override
            public Vector call(String data) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("Inside Vector call : ----- ");
                String vcS[] = data.split("-");
                double vc[] = new double[3];
                int i = 0;
                for (String vcSi : vcS) {
                    vc[i++] = Double.parseDouble(vcSi);
                }
                return Vectors.dense(vc);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Exception**

> Inside LabeledPoint call : -----  16/05/18 17:51:10 INFO Executor:
>   Finished task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 4). 953 bytes result sent to
>   driver 16/05/18 17:51:10 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in
>   stage 4.0 (TID 4) in 8 ms on localhost (1/1) 16/05/18 17:51:10 INFO
>   TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 4.0, whose tasks have all
>   completed, from pool  16/05/18 17:51:10 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage
>   4 (trainOn at SLRPOC.java:33) finished in 0.009 s 16/05/18 17:51:10
>   INFO DAGScheduler: Job 6 finished: trainOn at SLRPOC.java:33, took
>   0.019578 s 16/05/18 17:51:10 ERROR DataValidators: Classification labels should be 0 or 1. Found 1 invalid labels 16/05/18 17:51:10 INFO
>   JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1463574070000 ms.1 from job
>   set of time 1463574070000 ms 16/05/18 17:51:10 ERROR JobScheduler:
>   Error running job streaming job 1463574070000 ms.0
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Input validation failed.     at
>   org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.GeneralizedLinearAlgorithm.run(GeneralizedLinearAlgorithm.scala:251)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.StreamingLinearAlgorithm$$anonfun$trainOn$1.apply(StreamingLinearAlgorithm.scala:94)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.StreamingLinearAlgorithm$$anonfun$trainOn$1.apply(StreamingLinearAlgorithm.scala:92)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:42)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:399)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:40)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40)
>     at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:34)    at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:207)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:207)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:207)
>     at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)   at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:206)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Exception in thread "main"
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Input validation failed.     at
>   org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.GeneralizedLinearAlgorithm.run(GeneralizedLinearAlgorithm.scala:251)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.StreamingLinearAlgorithm$$anonfun$trainOn$1.apply(StreamingLinearAlgorithm.scala:94)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.StreamingLinearAlgorithm$$anonfun$trainOn$1.apply(StreamingLinearAlgorithm.scala:92)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:42)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:399)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:40)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40)
>     at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:34)    at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:207)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:207)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:207)
>     at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)   at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:206)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 16/05/18 17:51:10 INFO
>   StreamingContext: Invoking stop(stopGracefully=false) from shutdown
>   hook 16/05/18 17:51:10 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: foreachRDD at
>   SLRPOC.java:34 16/05/18 17:51:10 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 7 finished:
>   foreachRDD at SLRPOC.java:34, took 0.000020 s 16/05/18 17:51:10 INFO
>   JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1463574070000 ms.1 from job
>   set of time 1463574070000 ms 16/05/18 17:51:10 INFO ReceiverTracker:
>   Sent stop signal to all 2 receivers 16/05/18 17:51:10 INFO
>   ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Received stop signal 16/05/18 17:51:10 INFO
>   ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Stopping receiver with message: Stopped by
>   driver:  16/05/18 17:51:10 INFO ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Called
>   receiver onStop 16/05/18 17:51:10 INFO ReceiverSupervisorImpl:
>   Deregistering receiver 1 16/05/18 17:51:10 INFO
>   ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Received stop signal 16/05/18 17:51:10 INFO
>   ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Stopping receiver with message: Stopped by
>   driver:  16/05/18 17:51:10 INFO ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Called
>   receiver onStop 16/05/18 17:51:10 INFO ReceiverSupervisorImpl:
>   Deregistering receiver 0 16/05/18 17:51:10 ERROR ReceiverTracker:
>   Deregistered receiver for stream 1: Stopped by driver 16/05/18
>   17:51:10 INFO ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Stopped receiver 1 16/05/18
>   17:51:10 ERROR ReceiverTracker: Deregistered receiver for stream 0:
>   Stopped by driver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if you figured this out already, but your using an Binary algorithm which only allows 2 classification, 0 or 1. If you want to have more you need to use a multiple classification algorithm

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.{LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS, LogisticRegressionModel}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics
new LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS().setNumClasses(10)
```

Comment: LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS is not the option here as it does not support online learning, thanks for caring to answer on this old post.